# RDLC Report (Stored Procedure) with Parameters

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, rdlc

[Data display in dataset after specifying parameters for stored procedure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lt0V7.jpg)

[RDLC report just display the report headers but no data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1JOt.jpg)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    DataTable ResultsTable = new DataTable();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'DataSet1.sp_GetRent1' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.sp_GetRent1TableAdapter.Fill(this.DataSet1.sp_GetRent1, "@RentNo1", "@AppPath");
        //this.GetSPResult();
        this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        reportViewer1.Visible = true;
        reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Report1.rdlc";
        reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
        reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource("DataSet1",dt));

        GetSPResult();
    }

    private DataTable GetSPResult()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=RentACar1;Integrated Security=True");// ProviderName = "System.Data.SqlClient");

        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_GetRent1",conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RentNo1", "9905-10-2017");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AppPath", @"E:\Rent A Car\RentACar1\RentACar\bin\Debug");

            conn.Open();
            //cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            SqlDataAdapter adaptor = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            adaptor.SelectCommand = cmd;
            adaptor.Fill(ResultsTable);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

        return ResultsTable;
    }
}
```

This code doesn't show anything in the RDLC report.

If I open `dataset1.xsd` and specify the same parameters to the stored procedure, I get back values in the grid. But I am unable to get the values in the RDLC report.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: You should be *polite* and add "please" - but even then - I'm sorry, I don't know what the problem in your case is, so I really cannot give you a solution.

Comment: dear, i can share my code and store procedure with you. i hope you will find the problem and solve it.

Comment: Asking the same question again will not get you answers...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46837419/rdlc-report-stored-procedure-with-2-parameters?noredirect=1#comment80622833_46837419